# Measure Accuracy using Statistical Tool

Tags: statistics

I want to measure the accuracy of my GPS Receiver module. The real coordinates are obtained from the Google Maps, and the actual received coordinates are the ones that the GPS receiver received. I tried searching for statistical tools that can somehow support my findings. I tried using Chi-square test in Microsoft Excel, but I don't know how to interpret the results. How do I interpret the result? Or what statistical tool is really fit for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend finding the lat/lon differences in total or principal. Then with that you can get an average and variance. Then you can normalize and just use a standard z table.

go here:
http://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/chi-square.aspx

and here:

http://www.statlect.com/probability_exercises.htm

Comment: I assumed that the location obtained from the Google Maps is the real coordinates. Then, I tested the GPS by putting it in the same spot as the location i clicked in Google maps. Using an app, i determined the coordinates of the GPS, that is my actual reading.